# Regex - positive lookahead without group matching

Tags: regex

is ti possible to have positive lookahead group that would not be addedto the final groups?
I can't seem to use `?:` with `?=` already in the group but I want to just check if the group with lookahead is present but not use it in the end.

So when I pass some text to that regex I want to check if the general pattern matches (that's why I'm using positive lookahead) but I want to extract only number.

Here are examples - https://regex101.com/r/Q7WIUo/2

-> all above correct, I want to find the last number before magicalword but it has to contain XXX or YYY or ZZZ before. But as you can see I have 3 groups matching and I need only 2nd one - is it possible?

Comment: Just replacing the capturing groups with non-capturing groups seems to work just fine https://regex101.com/r/Q7WIUo/3 can you explain why that doesn't accomplish what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single capturing group to capture the last number before `magical word`, so you could omit the capturing group in the lookahead and the capturing group around the last part `(\D*)`:

```
^(?=.*\s(?:XXX|YYY|ZZZ)\s).*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\D*\bmagicalword\b\D*$
```

Instead of using `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` (your example data only contains decimal values separated by a dot) you could still use `([0-9,.]+)` but that is a bit of a broad match as it could also capture `...`

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `*\s(?:XXX|YYY|ZZZ)\s` Match one of the listed options inside a non capturing group
- `)` Close positive lookahead
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline non greedy
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Match 1+ digits with an optional part to match a dot and 1+ digits
- `\D*` Match 0+ times not a digit
- `\bmagicalword\b` Match the magical word between word boundaries
- `\D*` Match 0+ times not a digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M62AME/1)

If the string can also start with XXX YYY or ZZZ you could change the first `\s` in a word boundary

`(?=.*\b(?:XXX|YYY|ZZZ)\s`